# Ideas to configure the application.server param dynamically for Kafka Streams remote interactive queries on a spring boot app running on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am deploying a Kafka Streams application on Kubernetes replicated as several pods. This pods are exposed as a Kubernetes service so I have a common entry point that load balances the traffic: myapp:8080

The point is I want to run an interactive query that could be remote so I have set it up according to the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#querying-remote-state-stores-for-the-entire-app)

The web layer is provided by a spring boot application running on port 8080.

My question is how to configure dynamically the `application.server` param with a unique endpoint per pod.

**UPDATE:**

I guess what I need is to configure the `application.server` with the value of the kubernetes endpoint assigned to each pod:

```
$>kubectl get ep
NAME                    ENDPOINTS                       AGE
myapp   10.8.2.85:8080,10.8.2.88:8080   10d
```

- Pod1 -> `application.server`= 10.8.2.85:8080
- Pod2 -> `application.server`= 10.8.2.88:8080

However printing the `System.getEnv()` of the applications I only have the ip and port of the kubernetes service, not the assigned pod endpoint:

```
MYAPP_SERVICE_PORT=8080
MYAPP_SERVICE_HOST=10.11.248.5
...
```

So how can I get the kubernetes endpoint of the pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to get the endpoint ip of each pod by adding it as an environment variable this way:

**kubernetes deployment:**

```
spec:
  ...
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
          - name: POD_IP
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.podIP
          ...
```

Now I can access the pod ip/port and assign it to the `application.server` parameter in each instance of the application:

```
private final Environment environment;

@Autowired
public SomeController(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
}

...
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_SERVER_CONFIG, System.getEnv("POD_IP") + ":" + environment.getProperty("local.server.port"));
```

Comment: Hi @codependent, did you have any access issues making request calls to other Kafka Stream instances (2 app instances) when they are deployed on Kubernetes? using podIP + port I get a 404 not found for requests to the external rest api

Comment: Are your pods part of the same Service where you specify ReplicaSet=2 on deploy? Also is the port the same local.server.port you see with kubectl get svc?